# Exclude two specific points from joining in list plot

Tags: plotting

I am using `ListPlot` to plot a set a data, as shown below. However, I don't want any joining line between two points {-0.1, 0.042} and {0.1, 0.042} crossing the y-axis. Could you suggest any way to do that?

```
ARRAY = {{-1, 0.235}, {-0.4, 0.23}, {-0.3, 0.21}, {-0.2, 
   0.15849025910785963`}, {-0.1, 0.042}, {0.1, 0.042}, {0.2, 
   0.158}, {0.3, 0.214}, {0.4, 0.233}, {0.9, 0.235}}


ListPlot[ARRAY, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

Comment: try `ListPlot[SplitBy[ARRAY, Sign@*First], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]`?

Comment: @kglr
Thanks. It worked. However, if there are two arrays (e.g. 
```ListPlot[{ARRAY1,ARRAY2}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]```), it does not work. Any suggestion, please?

Comment: @PoreyS Please post `{ARRAY1,ARRAY2}` in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completing @kglr 's answer for several lists. Suppose the second list is `array2=2 array`. (Sorry, using uppercase for your symbols is bad programming practice because they may interfere with built-in symbols such as `E`, `I`, `N`, and others; get used to starting your symbols with lowercase). The code that does what you want is

```
ListPlot[Flatten[SplitBy[#, Sign@*First] & /@ {array, array2}, 1], 
 Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

To explain, `Sign@First` gives the sign of the first element of each member of your list; but we use the `Composition` sign, `@*` to nest the commands. You could get the same result by making them into a pure fuction, replacing that part with `Sign[First[#]]&`. As the second argument of `SplitBy`, it splits your list and produces separate lists when the sign changes. Using `#` in the position where @kglr had your list and following with a `&` creates a pure function which can apply to any list. We could apply it to `array` by `SplitBy[#,...]&@array` but instead we thread it over each member of `{array, array2}` by following it with `/@`. So that `Plot` sees four lists, we flatten the result by one with `Flatten[...,1]`. If you want to make the two halves of each plot have the same color, then define them so, e.g., with `PlotStyle->{Green,Green,Red,Red}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
L = ListPlot[ARRAY[[#, All]] & /@ {1 ;; 5}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];

R = ListPlot[ARRAY[[#, All]] & /@ {6 ;; 10}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All];

Show[R, L, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the same data as @NicholasG, another variant could be to do post processing.

```
array = {{-1, 0.235}, {-0.4, 0.23}, {-0.3, 0.21}, {-0.2, 
   0.15849025910785963`}, {-0.1, 0.042}, {0.1, 0.042}, {0.2, 
   0.158}, {0.3, 0.214}, {0.4, 0.233}, {0.9, 0.235}}
array2 = 2 array


ListLinePlot[{array, array2}
  , PlotStyle -> {Red, Darker@Green}
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[
    LineLegend[{Red, Darker@Green}, {"a1", "a2"}], {0.8, 0.2}]
  , Epilog -> {
    AbsolutePointSize[5]
    , Red, Point /@ array
    , Darker@Green, Point /@ array2
    }
  ] /. Line[j__] :> Line[SplitBy[j, Sign@*First]]
```

[image]